# looking at the source code of YUI and am wondering a few things

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, comments

I noticed that every method has comments in the source like:

```
    /**
    * @private
    * @method _onDropOver
    * @param Event e The Event Object
    * @description Handles the DropOver event to append a drop node to an empty target
    */
```

I am curious-- This looks like something out there reads it an turns it into documentation..  ?

...  Also, I've seen a few .js files where they actually say:
{'version': '@version'}...

And just wondered, where does the @version come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, something turns it into documentation. Check out the following link:

> http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuidoc/#start

which reads as:

> **Overview of YUI Doc Concepts**
>   YUI Doc is Comment-Driven
>   YUI Doc is a comment-parsing engine. It looks at comment-blocks in source files to find specific tags; when it finds a comment with a supported tag, it attempts to parse the comment and aggregate its information into the metadata it builds about your JavaScript application. Comment blocks should take the form of:

```
/**
 *
 * @tagname tagcontent
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jsDoc.](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/)